# How to determine constants when taking the derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was doing my pre-exam revision and I seem to have gotten confused by thinking too much. I have the following derivative: $\dfrac d{dx}(xy)$.
Now the my textbook tells me to use the product rule, but can't I just determine "$y$" as a constant, take it out of the derivative using the constant rule and evaluate the derivative of "$x$" with respect to "$x$" as $1$.

Thanks,

p.s. I'm sure I have went against many formatting conventions, please forgive me.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The procedure you describe is for the *partial* derivative $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy) = y$$ But when you have a *total* derivative (or gradient as you may see it in future coursework), $\frac{d}{dx}$, the assumption your book is making is that $xy = xy(x)$ i.e. $y$ is a function of $x$. So the use of product rule $$\frac{d}{dx}(xy) = y + xy'$$ is warranted.

Comment: Like Mr. Munshi said, if $y$ is a variable just like $x$, then your method would work, but if $y$ is a function of $x$, then you would have to use the product rule.

Comment: Is that derivative *all* you have? Because there really should be more, like some description of which variables you can consider to be functions of whichever variables. If there isn't, then that's a very poorly written question.

Comment: Let $f=xy$, where $y=x^3$ then your method will give $x^3$ but real result is $4x^3$, then your method is wrong if $y$ is not constant. You can consider $y$ as constant only if you know that $y$ is constant, or when you are taking partial derivative, which has other denotation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Generally, the fact that $y$ is constant or not must be following from context.

Answer (score 1):

In actual uses of mathematics you'll generally know whether $y$ is a constant or a variable based on what it represents in your particular problem.

In the context of an exam where all that is written is $\frac d{dx}(xy),$ the usual assumption is that $y$ is a function of $x,$ and if you don't want to lose marks the best test-taking strategy is best to go along with this assumption. I don't necessarily agree with problems being presented that way (not specifying anything about the relationship of $y$ and $x$), but I will not be the one writing your exams.

Note that the solution using the product rule works just as well if you find out later that $y$ actually does not vary with $x$; just treat $y$ as a constant function of $x.$

Answer (score -2):

No constants arise here, $(x,y)$ are variables. By Product Rule

$\dfrac d{dx}(xy)= x \dfrac {dy}{dx}+ y$.